# NOT NULL if value is true in another column

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm creating my entities and I want to create an entity with two columns that need to have a specific constraint. If addressId is defined, then extAddressId can be null (and it has to be null).

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="widgets")
 */
class Widget
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $addressId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $extAddressId;
}
```

I know how to do it with SQL but not with doctrine.

```
CREATE TABLE widgets
(
id integer,
addressId integer,
extAddressId integer,
CONSTRAINT if_addressId_then_extAddressId_is_not_null 
   CHECK ( (NOT addressId) OR (extAddressId IS NOT NULL) ) 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#column) you can add check constraints like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"check":"[your check condition]"})
 */
private $addressId;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"check":"[your check condition]"})
 */
private $extAddressId;
```

Haven't tested myself.